# AirConsole Controller Generator

Tags: airconsole

I am having trouble figuring out the messages sent by controllers built using the AirConsole Controller Generator.  I created a simple controller with a dpad, two middle buttons labeled Start and Back and two vertical buttons Jump and Attack and included the airconsole-controls folder in the directory.  I am able to test my game using the simulator and my controller is displayed and the virtual buttons are clickable but the messages aren't being sent or received by the game correctly.

I did use the demo controller for the pong game and was able to correctly use the up and down buttons within my game so the issue is with the controller I generated or my understanding of the button messages that are sent from it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

The generator always sends an object with a automatic- or self-defined key (depending on the element):

```
{
  'element-key': {
    message: <Object>,
    pressed: <Boolean>
}
```

To use the data which was send by - for example a dpad - you can do s.t. like this:

```
// On the 'Screen-Side'
airconsole.onMessage = function(device_id, data) {
  if (data.hasOwnProperty('dpad-left')) {
    var message = data['dpad-left'].message;
    var is_pressed = data['dpad-left'].pressed;
  }
};
```

Otherwise try to write a console.log(data) within the onMessage method and see if anything is received.

Let me know if this helped you!